# How to achieve coplanar card layout in flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

I'm trying to achieve a coplanar/disallined card collection layout in flutter. This is on Card layout on material Design documentation https://i.stack.imgur.com/x16su.jpg

I''ve tried with a GridView.count layout, but can't figure out how to disalline items. I also found out that there are user created libraries like this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view that can help with what I want to do, but I'd prefer an official solution since this layout is on the material design documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the "official solution" for creating this is, but I believe it would be something along the lines of "Create three list views with three scroll controllers, one of which is offset from the other two, and then sync up their scroll controllers, accounting for the offset."

I didn't know if this would work or not, so I created this dartpad in order to test it:
https://dartpad.dev/f9c8f00b78899d3c8c4a426d3466a8a3

Just in case the dartpad doesn't work, here is the code that I used:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ScrollSync(),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollSync extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScrollSyncState createState() => _ScrollSyncState();
}

class _ScrollSyncState extends State<ScrollSync> {
  CustomScrollController _controller1 =
      CustomScrollController(keepScrollOffset: true);
  CustomScrollController _controller2 = CustomScrollController(
      initialScrollOffset: 150.0, keepScrollOffset: true);
  CustomScrollController _controller3 =
      CustomScrollController(keepScrollOffset: true);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller1.addListener(() =>
        _controller2.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(
            _controller1.offset, "1 listen 2"));
    _controller1.addListener(() =>
        _controller3.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(
            _controller1.offset, "1 listen 3"));
    _controller2.addListener(() =>
        _controller1.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(
            _controller2.offset, "2 listen 1"));
    _controller2.addListener(() =>
        _controller3.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(
            _controller2.offset, "2 listen 3"));
    _controller3.addListener(() =>
        _controller1.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(
            _controller3.offset, "3 listen 1"));
    _controller3.addListener(() =>
        _controller2.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(
            _controller3.offset, "3 listen 2"));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller1.dispose();
    _controller2.dispose();
    _controller3.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Scroll Sync"),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _controller1,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => Container(
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                width: 150,
                height: 300,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "$index",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _controller2,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => Container(
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "$index",
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .display2
                        .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _controller3,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => Container(
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "$index",
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .display2
                        .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomScrollController extends ScrollController {
  CustomScrollController(
      {double initialScrollOffset = 0.0,
      keepScrollOffset = true,
      debugLabel,
      String controller})
      : super(
          initialScrollOffset: initialScrollOffset,
          keepScrollOffset: keepScrollOffset,
          debugLabel: debugLabel,
        );

  @override
  _SilentScrollPosition createScrollPosition(
    ScrollPhysics physics,
    ScrollContext context,
    ScrollPosition oldPosition,
  ) {
    return _SilentScrollPosition(
      physics: physics,
      context: context,
      oldPosition: oldPosition,
      initialPixels: initialScrollOffset,
    );
  }

  void jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(
      double value, String controller) {
    assert(positions.isNotEmpty, 'ScrollController not attached.');
    for (_SilentScrollPosition position
        in new List<ScrollPosition>.from(positions))
      position.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(value, controller);
  }
}

class _SilentScrollPosition extends ScrollPositionWithSingleContext {
  _SilentScrollPosition({
    ScrollPhysics physics,
    ScrollContext context,
    ScrollPosition oldPosition,
    double initialPixels,
  }) : super(
          physics: physics,
          context: context,
          oldPosition: oldPosition,
          initialPixels: initialPixels,
        );

  void jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(
      double value, String controller) {
    print(controller);
    print(value);
    print(pixels);

    if (controller[0] == "2") {
      if (pixels + 150.0 != value) {
        forcePixels(value - 150.0);
      }
    } else if (controller[9] == "2") {
      if (pixels - 150.0 != value) {
        forcePixels(value + 150.0);
      }
    } else if (pixels != value) {
      forcePixels(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: that is exatly what I was looking for. thank you very much, I'm pretty new to flutter and I have a long road to go

Comment: great! would you mind selecting my answer and upvoting it? I'd really appreciate it!! That was fun to do... I had never thought of scrolling in that fashion.  Thanks for the question!

Comment: I see that you're a new user... if you don't mind, the people that post answers here (like me) do it for a variety of reasons... one of which are the reputation points, and the different things that they unlock.  If you like an answer that you receive, it would greatly help them (and me) if you would select it, and give their post and upvote.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. I tried immediately to upvote but I need 15 reputation points for that. I just found out how to select the best answer. Thank you again